# What are the advantages of providing an until loop construct?

Tags: language-design, while-loop

An until loop construct `until (x)` can almost always be achieved with a while loop `while (!x)`. What's a possible reasoning behind having it available when a language also provides a while loop?

Comment: By "until loop" do you mean do-while loop?

Comment: @Ginger `until(x)` means `while(!x)`.

Comment: I see it the same way I see [Perl's `unless`](https://www.perltutorial.org/perl-unless/). As in, just more filler.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Although Ginger's answer is an excellent one, this really just comes down to aesthetics.

Comment: I only know two languages that have an until loop: PARI/GP and Haskell. In PARI/GP, `until` is in fact do-while-not, but there isn't an do-while loop. Haskell doesn't even have a while loop, and `until` is a function of type `(a -> Bool) -> (a -> a) -> a -> a`.

Comment: @UnrelatedString [And that’s ok!](https://languagedesign.meta.stackexchange.com/a/220/269)

Answer (score 8):

## Clarity in beginner languages

A construct like this could be helpful in a language designed for new programmers, like Scratch. "until x" may sound more natural than "while not x" to a new developer.

Comment: I admit my logic here is rather tenuous, but I can't think of any other good reason to have this construct.

Comment: Some languages have a `unless` keyword for the same purpose

Answer (score 6):

## `while let` and `until let`

In Swift, `while let` allows you to call a function repeatedly and loops until it returns nil:

```swift
// Simple cat program. readLine (builtin) reads a single line from stdin, and
// returns nil when there's no input left.
while let line = readLine() {
  // Because we made it here, we know line is not nil.
  print(line)
}
// readLine returned nil, so we're done.
```

But what if you want to loop until something returns *non*-nil?

```swift
var next: Task?
repeat {
  next = getNextTask()
} while next == nil
guard let next else { fatalError("unreachable") }
```

Blech, that's a mess. If Swift had `until let`, this code would be simpler:

```swift
until let task = getNextTask() {
  // task isn't usable here; even if it were, its value would always be nil.
}
// task is usable here, and known to not be nil.
```

Comment: This would function basically the same as rusts `loop {if task = getNextTask(){break task} }` construct

Comment: That's true, but Swift loops are not expressions, and you can't `break` with a value.

Comment: Your `until let` basically turns the loop into a expression with immediate assignment

Answer (score 5):

In addition to Ginger's answer, I have 2 things to add:

1. Avoiding some errors. They can prevent errors from a mistakenly negated condition in a while loop.
2. Readability. It is more clear the programmers intention, making the code more readable.

Answer (score 2):

## Code Golf

In Code Golf, where most of us come from, you try to make your code as short as possible. `until x` is shorter than `while not x` and is also shorter than `while !x`.

Answer (score 1):

### Run the block at least once

In languages that use keywords to delimit blocks (rather than braces or indentation), e.g. `If cond`…`Endif` and `While cond`…`EndWhile`, a `Repeat`…`Until cond` provides a way to get the block run at least once. A language could even allow `While condA`…`Until condB` for full control. Putting an "until" after a block also feels quite natural, as in "do this until that happens". An example of a language that has this [is APL](https://help.dyalog.com/latest/#Language/Control%20Structures/while.htm), e.g.:

```
:While 100>i
:AndIf 100>j
    (i j)←foo i j
:Until 100<i+j
:OrIf i<0
:OrIf j<0
```